# How to Make Color Palette in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a color Selector and now I want that when a user selects a particular color then it should display a corresponding palette of 5 colors. I can get the color which the user have selected but I am not able to find anything about how to make a palette according to that color.

I have tried taking that color and changing its `RGB` value to get nearby color patterns but I am not able to get the desired results as the change in RGB value changes color a lot but I want that color to be in contrast of the selected color.

Please Help, Thanks.

Comment: Unless you are learning how to make custom controls you can use [Coding4Fun](https://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) color picker control. It does what you need. You can also learn how the control works by looking into its source code.

Comment: i am already using color picker of Coding4Fun but it only allows to select color but i want to make a palette using that color in which there will be 5 colors corresponding to that color ... can you help in this...

Comment: This largely depends on how variant you want the colors be from the original one. In general, you would want to look up for the highest value between R,G,B and only modify that for your 5 colors.